# Simple_form and Rails - multiple choice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, simple-form

I'm trying to make a form with **simple_form** and there is multiple choice part. All the data is saved (I have name, surname, email...), but the multiple choice radio button is always an empty string.
How do I make a simple list of choices and save that choice?

Schema:

```
create_table "greetings" do |t|
  t.string "first_name"
  t.string "last_name"
  t.string "nickname"
  t.string "multiple_choice"
end
```

Controller:

```ruby
def new
  @greeting = Greeting.new
end

def create
  @greeting = Greeting.new(greeting_params)
  @greeting.save
end

private
  def greeting_params
    params.require(:greeting).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :nickname, :multiple_choice)
  end
```

Logs:

> Started POST "/greeting" for ::1 at 2017-07-28 17:32:19 +1000
>   Processing by GreetingsController#create as HTML Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...",
>   "greeting"=>{"first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Doe",
>   "nickname"=>"Johnny", "multiple_choice"=>""},
>   "multiple_choice"=>"Name", "commit"=>"Submit"} (0.2ms)  BEGINSQL
>   (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "greetings" ("first_name", "last_name",
>   "nickname", "multiple_choice", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1,
>   $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["first_name", "John"],
>   ["last_name", "Doe"], ["nickname", "Johnny"], ["multiple_choice", ""],
>   ["created_at", 2017-07-28 07:32:19 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-07-28
>   07:32:19 UTC]]

I want to make this multiple choice by:

- Name
- Surname
- Nickname

I tried in `view.slim`:

```
= simple_form_for @contact_form do |f|
= f.input :first_name, label: 'First name', placeholder: 'Enter first name...'
= f.input :last_name, label: 'Last name', placeholder: 'Enter last name...'
= f.input :nickname, label: 'Nickname', placeholder: 'Enter nickname...'
= f.input :multiple_choice, :collection => ['Name'], :as => :radio_buttons
= f.input :multiple_choice, :collection => ['Surname'], :as => :radio_buttons
= f.input :multiple_choice, :collection => ['Nickname'], :as => :radio_buttons
```

But it saves an empty string.

Thanks!

Comment: Post your controller code along with logs that are fired upon form submit

Comment: Post the full logs please including everything.

Comment: I pasted the logs as requested, I hope it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your  simple form that you have set up? the entire view?

Comment: I updated it, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for radio buttons:

```
view.slim:

p Name
= f.radio_button :call_time, 'first_name'
p Surname
= f.radio_button :call_time, 'last_name'
p Nickname
= f.radio_button :call_time, 'nickname'
= f.button :submit
```